# Remove group by from query with same result

Tags: oracle, group-by

Can anyone help regarding below query, that i want to modify it without using group by and in the same time i get the same result.

```
 SELECT     EMPLOYEE_ID           ,
           FIRST_NAME            ,
           LAST_NAME             ,
           EMAIL                 ,
           PHONE_NUMBER          ,
           HIRE_DATE             ,
           JOB_ID                ,
           SALARY                ,
           NVL(COMMISSION_PCT,0) ,
           MANAGER_ID            ,
           DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM       EMPLOYEES
WHERE      EMPLOYEE_ID
IN         (SELECT MANAGER_ID
            FROM   EMPLOYEES)
OR         DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
                            FROM   DEPARTMENTS
                            WHERE  UPPER(DEPARTMENT_NAME) = 'SALES')
OR         TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'YYYY')<=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-10
GROUP BY   EMPLOYEE_ID      ,
           FIRST_NAME       ,
           LAST_NAME        ,
           EMAIL            ,
           PHONE_NUMBER     ,
           HIRE_DATE        ,
           JOB_ID           ,
           SALARY           ,
           COMMISSION_PCT   ,
           MANAGER_ID       ,
           DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING     AVG(SALARY) > 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution as below :

```
SELECT     E.EMPLOYEE_ID           ,
           E.FIRST_NAME            ,
           E.LAST_NAME             ,
           E.EMAIL                 ,
           E.PHONE_NUMBER          ,
           E.HIRE_DATE             ,
           E.JOB_ID                ,
           E.SALARY                ,
           NVL(E.COMMISSION_PCT,0) ,
           E.MANAGER_ID            ,
           E.DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM       EMPLOYEES E
WHERE      EMPLOYEE_ID
IN         (SELECT MANAGER_ID
            FROM   EMPLOYEES)
OR         DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
                            FROM   DEPARTMENTS
                            WHERE  UPPER(DEPARTMENT_NAME) = 'SALES')
OR         TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'YYYY')<=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-10
OR         SALARY > (SELECT AVG(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES E2 WHERE E2.DEPARTMENT_ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```